Can I create a netplan that adds a default route between specific interfaces?
I have an Ubuntu 20.04 system with three NICs.  I want to isolate them: one for management traffic and the other two other traffic.  Call them MGT, T1, and T2.
Unless I'm missing something, the Ubuntu installer isn't sophisticated enough to set up the VRF for isolation so this is my thought:

tell the installer enough to set up the management port, Mgt
once the system is booted, add configuration to set up T1 and T2 on a VRF

The installer created /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    MGT:
      addresses:
      - 192.168.11.78/24
      gateway4: 192.168.11.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 1.2.3.4 
        - 8.8.8.8
        search:
        - mydomain.com
  version: 2

Where 1.2.3.4 (not the real address) is an in-house DNS server.
I'd like to create a 10-setup-isolated-traffic.yaml that configures T1 and T2 so any traffic coming in T1 gets routed to T2 (and vice versa).  I could do this with iptables physdev rules but I want the server to show up on traceroute so I think I need routing.
The best I've done so far is something like:
network:
  ethernets:
    T1:
      addresses: [192.168.99.46/30]
      routes:
        - to: 10.10.0.0/16
          via: 192.168.99.45
        - to: 10.20.0.0/16
          via: 192.168.99.45
    T2:
      addresses: [192.168.99.50/30]
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 192.168.99.49
  version: 2

But this is fragile because every time I add a subnet to my network, I have to add it to the list of routes for T1.  What I'd like is something that added a routing table for the two interfaces and added default routes back and forth.  But my routing skill and netplan knowledge is too weak to accomplish it. I've tried things that don't work and I'm kind of at the end of my rope.
Am I going about this all wrong?  Any suggestions on how to accomplish what I want or advice that what I want is wrong?  Thanks.

Forget netplan for a moment: are you able to manually produce your desired configuration? What does that look like?
